# Should I run measurement invariance if confirmatory factor analysis is not affirmative?

Tags: repeated-measures, pca, scales, psychometrics, confirmatory-factor

I have a repeated measures design for a Likert scale with 10 items. This scale is assumed to be unidimensional and this is one of the research questions along with the scales measurement invariance (MI) over time.

I conduct the analysis as follows: First assessment is randomly split into two pieces, I apply PCA in the one half, CFA in the second half and then I wish to make MI comparisons between the second half of the first assessment and the second assessment.

PCA is supporting a one factor construct but not very strongly (λ = 2.7, Prop: 73%) while CFA is problematic to provide one factor structure (c2/df > 3, RMSEA = 0.12, GFI = 0.87).

Under that circumstances does it make sense to run and provide also the necessary MI comparisons between the two assessments?

Comment: Regarding the CFA, might your problem be solved by dropping a problematic item?

Comment: It is an idea, however, I do not feel very comfortable to do so since my purpose is to validate the original 10 - item instrument in Greek.

Comment: Sure. That makes sense. Did you find a single factor at time two?

Comment: MI - measurement invariance?  (It could also be modification index, which cna be used in this context.

Comment: No it doesn't. Measurement invariance tests assume you have a fitting model to start wth, and you don't.

Comment: Also, don't use GFI as a measure of fit.

Comment: @Jeremy I'm precisely offering a bounty to provide a discussion of these aspects that can serve as a reference in the future. Are you willing to start?

Comment: Thank, you all for your useful comments as well as the bounty offer. Although, I have come up that it does not make sense to ask for measure invariance if scale structure is not clearly established, it would be nice to hear a comment from someone more experienced or someone experienced a similar situation.